# Display sheet data based on the sheet name

Tags: excel

I want to display data of sheet based on the sheet name. I want to get all the sheet names in a drop down list, and when a sheet is selected from the drop down list, the data from that sheet should get displayed.
I am getting the sheet names by {=""&MID(B2,FIND("]",B2)+1,256)&"""}
I can display the data from the other sheet using to formula {='Employee1'!B1"} where Employee1 is the sheet name. But I cant give a reference to the cell containing the sheet name like {='B1'!B1"} where B1 is the cell where the sheet name exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INDIRECT` function to refer to a cell specified by a text string, in your example like

```
=INDIRECT(B1&"!B1")
```